# How to get the squareroot of int* in C taken from mq_timedreceive

Tags: c, mq

I'm trying to take the sqrt of a variable int *msg in C.

I am trying to get the squareroot of message

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int *msg;
    ...
    while(N!=0) {
        if (g_continue == 0) {
            break;
        }
        if(mq_timedreceive(qdes, (char *)&msg, sizeof(int), 0, &ts) == -1){
            printf("Error Message Missing");
        }
        if(sqrt((float *)msg)*sqrt((float *)msg) == (int)sqrt((float *)msg)*(int)sqrt((float *)msg))
        {
            printf("%i %n %f", cID, msg, sqrt((float *)msg));
        }
        N--;
    }
}
```

any ideas how to make this work?

Comment: What type of warning/error are you getting? Did you included `<math.h>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`msg` is a pointer, and so is `(float *)msg`. Use `*(float *)msg` instead.

```
sqrt(*(float *)msg)
```

Howover, notice that you are **not** converting the `int` number into a `float`, you are *reading `msg` as a float*. Theres an important difference here, because the number `1` for instance, read as a float, is not `1.0f`. If you want to convert the value of `msg` to `float` keeping it's `int` meaning, use `(float)(*msg)` instead.

```
sqrt((float)(*msg))
```

I'm not sure what `mq_timedreceive()` does so I don't know which one is correct for you, so you will have to figure that out yourself.

In addition, make sure you initialized the pointer `int *msg` before using it. I don't know if you did, sinse you omitted part of your code.

Comment: I got that comparison between pointer and integer on the line that was (int)sqrt(*(float *)msg)*(int)sqrt(*(float *)msg) == msg how would I fix that? Other than that it worked perfectly thanks so much.

Comment: I think `sqrt(*msg)` is all you need, as C will apply the correct cast once you get it to an int. If you want to be explicit, sqrt((float)*msg).

Answer (score 0):

```
if (sqrt(*msg) * sqrt(*msg) == (int)sqrt(*msg) * (int)sqrt(*msg))
    printf("%i %n %f", cID, msg, sqrt(*msg));
```